# How to create an empty tf.Variable with None dimension

Tags: tensorflow

How to create empty tf.Variable. I try to make this but get errors

```
def __init__(self):
    super(ConcatLayer, self).__init__(dtype=tf.float64)
    self.total = tf.Variable(shape=tf.TensorShape([None, 3]), dtype=tf.float64)
```

ValueError: initial_value must be specified.

Which initial_value should I put?
Thx

Comment: How about zeros?

Comment: ValueError: Cannot convert a partially known TensorShape to a Tensor: (None, 3)

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following (only tested in TF 2.x),

```
import tensorflow as tf

v = tf.Variable([[0,0,0],[0,0,0]], shape=[None, 3])
```

As you can see, you **must** provide an initial value to a `tf.Variable`. But you can have `None` dimensions as shown. If you need to change the size of the first dimension (which we defined as `None`), you can do the following.

```
v = v.assign([[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0]])
```

Comment: Not exactly what I need but you have helped me to found the decision Thx

Answer (score 0):

```
self.total = tf.Variable((np.empty((0, 3), dtype=np.float64)), shape=[None, 3])
```

Comment: Consider adding details around your answer.